# Use Firebase Storage and Cloud Firestore "at the same time"

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a simple code with a ListView.builder connected to Cloud Firestore. Each List item looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there's a leading image. Until now, it is storage in a `assets/images/` folder. I want to add the images to Firebase Storage, so that each list item have a specific and unique image. The solutions I've seen to retrieve images uses `FutureBuilder` and `stream`, but I already use a `StreamBuilder` and `stream` for the Cloud Firestore.

I just want some light on what I can/need to do, there's no need of code. Can't think of a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible (and in fact, quite common) to nest `StreamBuilder`s and `FutureBuilder`s.

For example, if you have documents in Firestore, and each of those contains the URL of an image in Cloud Storage, you'll typically end up with:

1. a `StreamBuilder` for the Firestore documents, so that you can keep the UI in sync with the database.
2. a separate `FutureBuilder` for each image.

Since these are separate load operations, you need a separate `*Builder` for each of them. That is not a problem, and in fact working-as-intended.